How can I load a ros2 parameter config file independent of the namespace?
I have a setup where I have multiple modules running in the same ros2 network. Therefore, all of there nodes run under a namespace for that module.
I now have the problem that my config yaml file won't load the parameters from the config since the namespace is not specified there. I found that when I do specify the namespace in the config file as follows:
ns:
  node_name:
    ros__paramters:
      my_param: value

Then the parameter is loaded correctly. However, I do not know the namespaces beforehand and want them all the be the same anyway.
Currently, my workaround is to have the parameters under /** but I would like to avoid this since it results in all nodes having all parameters.
Is there a way to specify parameters in the config file under a node name and have them loaded irrespective of the namespace?
